# Jquery hover to display child element

Tags: jquery, hover

```
<div id="sidemenu">
<ul>
<li><table><tr><td><span>Welcome</span></td><td>&bull;</td></tr></table></li>
<li><table><tr><td><span>About</span></td><td>&bull;</td></tr></table></li>
<li><table><tr><td><span>Blog</span></td><td>&bull;</td></tr></table></li>
<li><table><tr><td><span>Contact</span></td><td>&bull;</td></tr></table></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The following HTML displays a sidemenu with anchored links (i've simplified the code for the sake of this example). I am trying to make the span text display when hovering over each bullet point in the menu. Is there a way to hover over a bullet point and display the corresponding span tag within each li tag?

Comment: [Like that?](http://dharman.eu/sites/dropColor/)

Comment: Or like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g87my/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hover` function, try this:

```
$('#sidemenu li').hover(
    function() { $('span', $(this)).show(); },
    function() { $('span', $(this)).hide(); } 
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6USUK/)